# Keeping image position while resizing browser window in css div

Tags: css

i'm using div and positioning to position my images in browser but when i resize my browser window the positions changes and mixed up with page texts. i want i way to make the element on the same place when changing window size or using smaller screens .
Thanks for your attention.

https://jsfiddle.net/20e6srmf/

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title{
  width: 100%;
  height: 39px;
  background-color: #0a1931;
}

.container-one{
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: end;
  padding: 9px;

}


.about-me{
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.skills{
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.cnt-me{
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}


.top-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;   /*378px */
  background-color: #292c6d ;
}

.container-two{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;

}


.astroid{
  width: 79px;
  height: 75px;
  float: right;
}


.rotate{
  transform: rotate(67deg);
}






#top-name{
  margin: 0px;
}

#star-1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 11px;
  top: 23px;

}

#star-2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 172px;
  left: 280px;

}

#star-3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  right: 70px;
  margin: 10px
}

}

#star-4{
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  right: 380px;
}



#star-5{
  position: absolute;
  top: 380px;
  left: 450px;
}

#star-6{
  position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    right: 560px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="title">
    <div class="container-one">
      <a class="cnt-me" href="#">one</a>
      <a class="skills" href="#">shonow</a>
      <a class="about-me" href="#">two</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="top-section">
    <div class="container-two">
      <img class="astroid rotate" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/centralized-network.png" alt="star">
      <h1 id=top-name>welcome to shonow world</h1>
      <h2>there are many things to do in shonow!</h2>
      <h3>let see!</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="stars-decore">

      <img id="star-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/centralized-network.png" alt="star">
      <img id="star-2" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/centralized-network.png" alt="star">
      <img id="star-3" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/centralized-network.png" alt="star">
      <img id="star-4" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/centralized-network.png" alt="star">
      <img id="star-5" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/centralized-network.png" alt="star">
      <img id="star-6" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/centralized-network.png" alt="star">

    </div>



  </div>


  <div class="mid-section">

  </div>

  <div class="bot-section">

  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice how some stars remain on the same place, while others move? The stars that keep their place use `right`, while those which move use `left`.

So, on the `#star-` ids in your css, change `left` to `right`, and adjust the pixels accordingly.

Comment: this wont work because if you change size at the right side of window right position elements change places and if u change at left side of window left position elements change places

Answer (score 0):

i think think the simple solution is that make a transparent layer of all elements and place it on my background.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).